# Особенности работы QDrag на разных платформах

Tags: c++, windows, qt5, drag-n-drop

Имеется такая задача: на некоем виджете имеется кнопка (`QAction`), по нажатию на которую создается Drag&Drop (`QDrag`) объект, после чего курсор мыши перемещается в область вложенного виджета и, после повторного нажатия, данные, установленные в `QDrag`, захватываются вложенным виджетом и отображаются. Под линуксом все оказалось довольно просто:

```
QMimeData *mime = new QMimeData{...};

QDrag *drag = new QDrag{this};
drag->setMimeData(mime);

drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction, Qt::CopyAction);
```

Но возникла проблема под windows: объект `QDrag` уничтожается сразу после создания. Как это исправить?

Comment: Проверил у себя аналогичный код, все работает как надо. В какой момент удаляется `QDrag`?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver а платформа windows? Сразу после отпускания левой кнопки мыши.

Comment: Тестировал на windows и mac. Удаляется после срабатывания dropEvent того виджета, куда бросаю. То есть да - после отпускания левой кнопки мыши, но после собственно дропа

Comment: @BeardedBeaver начнем сначала: для создания QDrag вы использовали QAction?

Comment: Попробую завтра с `QAction`, у меня были варианты с `QTreeWidget` и `QLabel`, оба работали как надо

Comment: @BeardedBeaver так в том то и дело, что при зажатой кнопке мыши все работает, но в QAction можно отследить только triggered, так что после отпускания конпки мыши объект разрушается сразу после создания в случае windowd, а в случае линукса все работает